# How can I add text to a sidecap figure outside the caption (so it does not appear in the list of figures)

Tags: captions, sidecap

How can I add a side caption outside of the `\caption` command in a `SCfigure`, so it doesn't appear in the list of figures?
I tried this but it does not work

```
\begin{SCfigure}
    \label{fig:my_figure}
    \includegraphics{images/some_image.png}
    \caption{Caption of my figure}
    Here is where i want to elaborate but it will not compile
\end{SCfigure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: The extra text compiled fine, it just didn't show up where you expected it.  (Putting in into a parbox would have helped, but it still would not have appeared below the caption.)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

You can use the optional argument of `\caption`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \listoffigures
    \begin{SCfigure}
        \label{fig:my_figure}
        \includegraphics{image.png}
        \caption[Caption of my figure]{Caption of my figure. Here is what I want to elaborate on.}
    \end{SCfigure}
\end{document}
```

The optional argumnet (in `[]`) is what is added to the list of figures and the mandatory argument (in `{}`) is what is displayed with the figure.
This works for normal (non-side) captions too.

Comment: Interestingly, SCfigure seems to set the caption width equal to the image width or to the remaining space (whichever is smaller).  If you want to put a large caption next to small image, I would use a normal figure and put the caption into a \parbox[b].